# Ifelse statements and inline comments in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to write a simple line that compares the number of rows (i.e. participants) to a previous number and spits out one of three options "lower than", "similar to", or "higher than".

I am using rmarkdown to create the document and the sentence looks like this

> `` This is `r if(nrow(Data)>1000) { print("higher than")} else if (nrow(Data) <900) { print("lower than")} else { print("similar to")}` previous years response levels. ``

Now in the console it spits out properly as

```
>  |.......................                                               |  33%
  ordinary text without R code
>  |...............................................                       |  67%
>label: unnamed-chunk-1 (with options) 
>List of 1
> $ include: logi FALSE
>  |......................................................................| 100%
>  inline R code fragments
>[1] "lower than"
```

But in the text file it then prints the sentence reads as

> This is previous years response levels.

Why is the ifstatement printing only in the console and not inline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Easy solution

You should write it this way:

> `` This is `r if(nrow(Data)>1000) {"higher than"} else if (nrow(Data) <900) {"lower than"} else {"similar to"}` previous years response levels. ``

You don't need a `print` statement.

---

### Why print doesn't work

The solution with `print` doesn't work because `print(x)` shows the `x` in console and returns `x` invisibly.

If you want to use `print` in your solution but you want to make it work, you need to apply `(...)` parentheses around your if-statement so to force visibility on invisible returns. Check out `?invisible` if you don't know what it means.

This is how to get your expected result retaining the `print` function:

> `` This is `r (if(nrow(Data)>1000) {print("higher than")} else if (nrow(Data) <900) {print("lower than")} else {print("similar to")})` previous years response levels. ``

---

### Reproducible example

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## Test

```{r}
Data <- data.frame(a = 1:1100)
```

This is `r if(nrow(Data)>1000) {"higher than"} else if (nrow(Data) <900) {"lower than"} else {"similar to"}` previous years response levels.

```{r}
Data <- data.frame(a = 1:800)
```

This is `r if(nrow(Data)>1000) {"higher than"} else if (nrow(Data) <900) {"lower than"} else {"similar to"}` previous years response levels.

```{r}
Data <- data.frame(a = 1:950)
```

This is `r if(nrow(Data)>1000) {"higher than"} else if (nrow(Data) <900) {"lower than"} else {"similar to"}` previous years response levels.
````

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask why the print command is not needed? Or is that the default option.